# PHP - move_uploaded_file after compressing image

Tags: php, upload, compression

I have an upload script in php that takes a file or multiple files and uploads them onto my server. I am now trying to compress the image down before uploading to save time and server space.

Both my compression function and upload functions work on their own but i cannot combine the two.

If i do the upload without compression, as in:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($temp, "../images/" . $upload)){
```

it works fine, but it's trying to move the compressed image not the full size one like here:

```
    // compression
    $compressed = compress_image($temp, $upload, 70);
    //

    if (move_uploaded_file($temp, "../images/" . $compressed)){
```

Full code is below:

```
function getExtension($str) {
    $ext = pathinfo($str, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    return $ext;
}

function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {
    $info = getimagesize($source_url);
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg'){$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);}
    else if ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif'){$image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);}
    else if ($info['mime'] == 'image/png'){$image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);}
    imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
    return $destination_url;
}


foreach ($_FILES["images"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        $temp = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$key];
        $extension = getExtension($name);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);
        $upload = $_POST['name'].'.'.$extension;

        // compression
        $compressed = compress_image($temp, $upload, 70);
        //

        if (move_uploaded_file($temp, "../images/" . $compressed)){
            echo "OK";
        }
        else{
            echo "ERROR";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are returning the wrong variable. You can also just safe your compressed file without `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: which variable should i be using? I've just removed the move_uploaded_file and have got the compressed file saving on the server, i have just read and heard that it's always safer to use that when uploading files in php?

Answer (score 0):

the documentation says that.

> If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and
>   move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.

i am guessing that it will only work on the original upload file. why don't you first `move_upload_file` and then do the compression.

Comment: if i do the compression after the move_uploaded_file then am i not having to wait for the full size image to upload anyway, therefore no real point?